# What is this ghost plane that appears with Multi-View Stereoscopy?

Tags: camera, stereoscopy

I just set up a rig of six cameras, and for some reason, after enabling **Stereoscopy** > **Multi-View** a plane appears that seems to be some sort of a guide, but the reason for its positioning is not clear.

[image]

Selecting different cameras in the Viewport doesn't make it change. Neither does selecting different cameras in the Stereoscopy list.

[image]

I would prefer not to have to tolerate this awkward plane off to right side of my cam rig (the active camera in the screenshot is the "Forward" cam). So if anyone knows why the plane is there or how to change its positioning/appearance, please share.

Other observations: Disabling Stereoscopy makes the ghost plane disappear. Switching the Stereoscopy mode to Stereo 3D puts it in front of my "Forward" cam (which is a *better* position, but since I need to use Multi-View this is not a solution - besides, I wouldn't mind the plane disappearing altogether).

Blender version: 2.9.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is your convergence plane, e.g. where the L/R cameras converge. You can turn it off in the N menu under View->Stereoscopy->Plane

[image]

Comment: Thank you for demystifying! Seeing as my cameras all face away from a central point and their fields of view don't overlap, I'll definitely be turning that off.  :-)